# How to configure post webhook from BitBucket to Kafka REST Proxy?

Tags: git, apache-kafka, bitbucket, webhooks, kafka-rest

I'm trying to post data(payload) from BitBucket to my Kafka instance in case of any BitBucket events (like `Pushed`, `Forked`, `PR creating`, `Addition`/`Modification`/`Deletion` of PR comments etc.)

So, I've setup Kafka rest-proxy but I can't send data from BitBucket to Kafka as the `Content-Type` required to post data using the [**Kafka REST proxy**](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/api.html) is `application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json` and BitBucket's payload has an header set as `application/json` (I'm using the default BitBucket webhook configured at the `Repository` level).

I've configured the Webhook at the repository level is this way:
[image]

This is the request which is being triggered from BitBucket's Webhook:

[image]

And the response I get from Kafka's REST Proxy is this:

[image]

I've thought about the following solutions:

1. I can write **a simple web server which acts as a mediator between the two systems (BitBucket and Kafka)**. The server can act as an intermediate proxy and grab incoming requests from BitBucket's webhook and post it to `Kafka REST proxy` using the appropriate header (`application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json`).

   This solution works but the downsides are maintenance of another server (written by me). Also, it can have **scalability woes** as BitBucket starts triggering webhooks frequently (100s per second during peak hours as we've only one BitBucket instance and we've around 3500 developers).
2. I can use **a BitBucket plugin** which works as a `webhook` and which allows me to configure and change headers on the fly. **This is the solution which I'm thriving to achieve**. Doesn't involve an extra server to be maintained as well.

**Is there a BitBucket plugin, which I can install from the market place which will enable me to configure the header when the webhook
    is triggered**?

P.S. - Apologies for writing such a long question. These two solutions are just from the top off my head. I won't be surprised if a better solution is available to integrate BitBucket with Kafka. Also, please do let me know if the question stands unclear. In that case, I'll try to clarify my question in a different manner.

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone please look into it? Please let me know if you need any clarification on the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pipedream](https://pipedream.com) to accept webhook requests from Bitbucket, modify the `Content-Type` header to `application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json`, and forward the request to your Kafka REST proxy. Running pipelines like this on Pipedream is free.

I created an [example pipeline](https://pipedream.com/@dylburger/bitbucket-kafka-rest-proxy-api-p_0WxCyz?e=1MeY1rTVqwxe0Wlt8EkJ3nfLvmV) that shows you how this works. It takes the HTTP payload sent from Bitbucket — `$event.body` — and uses a bit of Node.js code to forward the request on to another HTTP endpoint.

In my case I just added a RequestBin URL so you can see the body and headers being POSTed somewhere — check out an example request I sent [here](https://requestbin.com/r/entygbild98b/1MeY2I5Pvof8ehSKKBscTDq87kL). Expand the Headers section of that request and notice the `Content-Type` header is correctly set to `application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json`.

If you fork the pipeline above (just click the Fork button in the top-right), it should generate a custom URL specific to your pipeline. Add that URL as a new Bitbucket webhook URL tied to your repo, and you should start seeing new events come through.

This assumes your Kafka REST proxy URL is publicly-accessible. All the code for Pipedream pipelines is public, so if you want to keep your Kafka REST Proxy endpoint private, you can create an [environment variable](https://docs.pipedream.com/environment-variables/) and reference that in the Node.js code, replacing the RequestBin URL with the value of that environment variable.

For example, I might create an environment variable called `KAFKA_REST_ENDPOINT` and replace:

```
url: 'https://entygbild98b.x.pipedream.net'
```

with

```
url: process.env.KAFKA_REST_ENDPOINT
```

Let me know if this helps or if you have any other questions.